# VHDL Array Dekaration with Generic value in Package definition

Tags: vhdl

I am going to define an array type in a package so that I can use it as an output value.
The length of this array depends on a generic value.

I tried it in the line before the component declaration and after.
But both gave an error. Before was the generic type unknown and after was the type unknown by the output declaration.
How can I declare this type?

The Type is:

```vhdl
TYPE t_adc_data IS ARRAY((2**ir_sensor.nof_decoder_signals)-1 DOWNTO 0) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
```

```vhdl
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;
PACKAGE ir_sensor_pkg IS
    TYPE t_adc_data IS ARRAY((2**ir_sensor.nof_decoder_signals)-1 DOWNTO 0) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
    COMPONENT ir_sensor IS
        GENERIC(
            --generell
            nof_decoder_signals     : INTEGER := 4; -- number of lines to decoder
            -- for clock
            frequency_resolution    : INTEGER := 32;
            frequency_divider       : INTEGER := 200000; -- target 500Hz by a base frequency of 100MHz
            ratio                   : INTEGER := 8000; -- target 12.5KHz(80us) by a base frequenzy of 100MHz
            adc_trigger             : INTEGER := 7990; -- just a few clocks less than ratio
            -- for adc
            sclk_frequency          : INTEGER := 8000000; -- max 20Mhz
            base_clk                : INTEGER := 33000000 
        );
        PORT (
            -- generell
            isl_clk                 : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            isl_reset               : IN  STD_LOGIC;
            oslv_decoder_lines      : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(nof_decoder_signals -1 DOWNTO 0);
            -- puls gen
            osl_puls                : OUT STD_LOGIC;
            --adc
            osl_adc_sclk            : OUT  STD_LOGIC;   -- ADC clock
            osl_adc_csn             : OUT  STD_LOGIC;   -- ADC chip select not
            isl_adc_sdata           : IN   STD_LOGIC;   -- ADC serial data
            oslav12_hex_data        : OUT t_adc_data    -- ADC results out as array of hex values
        );
    END COMPONENT ir_sensor;
    -- or here 
    -- TYPE t_adc_data IS ARRAY((2**ir_sensor.nof_decoder_signals)-1 DOWNTO 0) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);
END PACKAGE ir_sensor_pkg
```

Comment: You have no declaration of `typedef_adc` . Where are you expecting to get this from?

Comment: Oh sorry by bad this shoud be "ir_sensor.nof_decoder_signals". I change it. Just a moment

But I don't know if this is needed

Comment: Generics cannot be taken from components. They are not set until the a component instantiation takes place. You can put a generic on a package if you can use vhdl 2008. If you are stuck with 1993 then you'll need to do the declaration in the region where the generic exists inside the entity or make it a literal.

Comment: Is it then possible to declare it inside the component?

Comment: Why not just leave the array unconstrained and size it on the port. `TYPE t_adc_data IS ARRAY(natural range <>) OF STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 DOWNTO 0);` ?

Comment: Another solution may be to declare `nof_decoder_signals` as a constant inside the package and refer to it in both the type declaration and component.

Answer (score 0):

We have a component declaration here and related generics are observable inside component body and its ports only. You cannot access generic parameters of component outside of component declaration by a method like you mentioned.